# How to create 301 redirect on AWS from 1 instance to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a web platform that was build originally on a .co.uk domain. The platform is hosted on nginx ec2 instance. I have now acquired the .com domain for my site and what to fully move over to that domain.

I have essentially replicated my current instance and pointed the .com at the new instance so both work fine in parallel at the moment.

However my Google search adds is all set up with the .co.uk domain and I need to change that using googles domain change tool. They say I should add 301 redirected to the new domain however I am struggling to fine any information on how to do this on AWS from 1 domain/ instance to another.

So I am wondering how I can do a 301 redirect from the old home page to the new domain? Is it possible to do via route 53?

I am wondering if it as simple as just this:

```
<?php
header("Location: https://www.newdomain.com/", true, 301);
exit();
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am wondering how I can do a 301 redirect from the old home page
> to the new domain? Is it possible to do via route 53?

No, Route53 just handles domain name resolution. Route53 doesn't handle HTTP requests/responses. A 301 is a specific type of HTTP response.

> I am wondering if it as simple as just this:
>
> ```
> <?php
> header("Location: https://www.newdomain.com/", true, 301);
> exit();
> ?>
> ```

That would tell anyone requesting the old domain, on any page, that the new page URL is `https://www.newdomain.com/`. It drops the path info from the request, which is almost certainly not what you want, and definitely not what Google is telling you to do.

I would recommend adding an Nginx configuration to handle requests to the old domain:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name olddomain.co.uk;
   return 301 $scheme://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

This will include the path info in the redirect.

Comment: Hello, 
thanks very much for this, it works perfect for my oldsite.co.uk and www.oldsite.co.uk 

However on the google domain change tool, when it tires to verify I get the following message
Redirect wasn’t found
https://www.oldsite.co.uk/

so the https://www is not being redirected for some reason. Wondering if you can also advise on this? 

Thanks

Comment: `oldsite.co.uk` and `www.oldsite.co.uk` are two separate web addresses. you need add both of those addresses to the `server_name` setting. And you also need to make sure that both records in your DNS server point to the Nginx server.

Comment: Oh apologies, I didn't realise the https :// www was cut out of my example. So www.oldsite.co.uk works, oldsite.co.uk works , https:// www .oldsite.co.uk does not work

Comment: That's because you only setup a redirect block on port `80`. Setup the same thing on port `443` 
assuming you already have HTTPS configured and working on port 443 in Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

you have to change your nginx configuration a bit to redirect.

open the `.conf` file present in your .co.uk site, at the `server{ }` block,

add this :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name domain.co.uk;
   return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

This will forward all the incoming requests to `www.domain.com` so that your all requests will be forwarded with only the change of `.co.uk` to `.com`

Hope this helps!